# Errors with the Flex Tool

Tags: lex, lexical-analysis

```
/*Regular Definitions*/
delim[\t\n]
WS{delim}+
letter[A-Za-z]
digit[0-9]
id{letter}({letter|digit})*
number{digit}+(\.{digit}+?(E[+-]?{digit}+)?

%%
{WS}{/*do nothing*/}
if{printf("\nIF found");return 0;}
then{printf("\nTHEN found");return 0;}
else{printf("\nELSE found");return 0;}
{id}{printf("\nID found");return 0;}
{number}{printf("\nNUMBER found");return 0;}
"<"{printf("\nLess than symbol found.");return 0;}
"<="{printf("\nLess than or Equals to symbol found.");return 0;}
"="{printf("\nEquals to symbol found.");return 0;}
"<>"{printf("\nNot equals to symbol found.");return 0;}
">"{printf("\nGreater than symbol found.");return 0;}
">="{printf("\nGreater than or equal to symbol found.");return 0;}
%%
```

While using flex to compile this

```
G:\>flex Lex.l
```

I get the following errors:

```
"Lex.l", line 14: unrecognized rule

"Lex.l", line 14: unrecognized rule

"Lex.l", line 14: unrecognized rule

"Lex.l", line 14: unrecognized rule

"Lex.l", line 14: unrecognized rule

"Lex.l", line 27: EOF encountered inside an action
```

Can anyone help me with it ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your question to add compile errors between code tags. It's easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

1.- Surround with brackets each expression of the alternation.

```
{letter}|{digit}
```

2.- A closing parentheses was missed in the `number` definition. I added it before first `?`, but not sure.

```
number{digit}+(\.{digit}+)?(E[+-]?{digit}+)?
```

3.- In the rule section, separate with spaces the pattern and the `C` code.

```
{WS}        {/*do nothing*/}
```

---

This should work, or at least compile:

```
/*Regular Definitions*/
delim[\t\n]
WS{delim}+
letter[A-Za-z]
digit[0-9]
id{letter}({letter}|{digit})*
number{digit}+(\.{digit}+?(E[+-]?{digit}+)?)

%%
{WS}        {/*do nothing*/}
if          {printf("\nIF found");return 0;} 
then        {printf("\nTHEN found");return 0;} 
else        {printf("\nELSE found");return 0;} 
{id}        {printf("\nID found");return 0;} 
{number}    {printf("\nNUMBER found");return 0;} 
"<"         {printf("\nLess than symbol found.");return 0;} 
"<="        {printf("\nLess than or Equals to symbol found.");return 0;} 
"="         {printf("\nEquals to symbol found.");return 0;} 
"<>"        {printf("\nNot equals to symbol found.");return 0;} 
">"         {printf("\nGreater than symbol found.");return 0;} 
">="        {printf("\nGreater than or equal to symbol found.");return 0;} 
%%
```

Comment: Thanks the above code does compile, but I get the following errors using Dev-cpp when trying to compile the c-file:

    [Linker error] undefined reference to `yywrap' 
    [Linker error] undefined reference to `yywrap' 
    [Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16' 
    ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @vs2010noob: In my linux it's all fine: `flex lex.l && cc -o exe lex.yy.c -lfl`. Make sure to link with flex library.